# Angular: Form fields generated from NgFor on array Of objects are wiped when Adding an Object to the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of ValidationStep which can be a have a SqlDetail or a documentDetail. There is a "type" field of the ValidationStep which will be "Sql" or "Document". If the type is Sql then the SqlDetail will be populated and documentDetail will be null and vice versa. A sqlDetail/documentDetail will have an array of SqlValidations/DocumentValidations

There are pictures futher below to explain better but I am generating an angular Mat tab for each ValidationStep and a set of form inputs for each SqlValdiation in the SqlValidationList inside SqlDetail. My form is being pre populated with an SqlDetail that has two SqlValidations.
When I add to the SqlValidations I log to the console the model(which is two way binded) using the "log button" and it has been added,a third set of form inputs is added however all fields are wiped despite the information in the model being correct.

My front end before I hit "add validation"

[image]

My log for ValidationSteps before I hit add validation

[image]

The front end after I hit "add Validation", a third row of inputs has been added but previous fields wiped
[image]

The log after the add,you can see the previous two sqlValidatons are there and the new one is gone.
[image]

Whats very strange is that if I first remove a validation( which removes the sqlValidation from the model and removes the set of inputs) and then add a Validation, it works fine.

My Models

ValidationStep

```
export class ValidationStep{
public id: number;
public automation_information_aId: number;
public sequence: number;
public type: string;
public documentDetail: DocumentDetail ;
public sqlDetail: SqlDetail;

 }
```

DocumentDetail

```
export class DocumentDetail{
public id: number;
public documentValidationList: DocumentValidation[];
public credential: CredentialNoSecret;
public locationType: string;
public locationUrl: string;
}
```

DocumentValidation

```
export class DocumentValidation{
public id: number;
public validationType: string;
private validationValue: string;
 }
```

SqlDetail

```
export class SqlDetail{
public id: number;
public sqlValidationList: SqlValidation[];
public credential: CredentialNoSecret;
public url: string;
public driver: string;
public query: string;
}
```

SqlValidation

```
export class SqlValidation{
public id: number;
public validationType: string;
public columnName: string;
public operator: string;
public validationValue: string;
    constructor(){
     this.id = 0;
   this.validationType ="";
    this.columnName= "";
    this.operator="";
            this.validationValue ="";
}



 }
```

My ts for the front end component, the add/remove sqlValidations step methods are near the top

```
import { ControlsService } from 'app/services/controls.service';
import { ControlSpecificDataService } from 'app/services/controlSpecificData.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelfServiceDetailsService } from 'app/services/self-service-details.service';
import { ParamMap, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ValidationStep } from './ValidationsModels/ValidationStep.model';
import { DocumentDetail } from './ValidationsModels/DocumentDetail.model';
import { SqlDetail } from './ValidationsModels/SqlDetail.model';
import { SqlValidation } from './ValidationsModels/SqlValidation.model';
export interface SqlDriver {
value: string;
viewValue: string;
 }
 export interface DocumentLocationType {
 value: string;
 viewValue: string;
}
export interface SqlValidationType {
value: string;
viewValue: string;
}
export interface SqlOperators {
 value: string;
  viewValue: string;
 }
  @Component({
selector: 'addEditControl',
templateUrl: 'add-edit-control.component.html',
styleUrls: ['form.css'],
providers: [ControlsService, ControlSpecificDataService,SelfServiceDetailsService]
 })

 export class AddEditControlComponent{
controlId: String;
validationSteps: ValidationStep[];
sqlDrivers: SqlDriver[] = [
  // these map to the enums in the java object
  //for the dropdown in the form
  {value: 'ORACLE', viewValue: 'Oracle'},
  {value: 'MICROSOFT', viewValue: 'Microsoft SQL Server'},
  {value: 'MYSQL', viewValue: 'MySQL'}
];
documentLocationTypes: DocumentLocationType[] = [
  // these map to the enums in the java object
  //for the dropdown in the form
  {value: 'SHAREPOINT', viewValue: 'Sharepoint'}
];
sqlValidationTypes: SqlValidationType[] = [
  // these map to the enums in the java object
  //for the dropdown in the form
  {value: 'RowCount', viewValue: 'Row Count'},
  {value: 'AnyRowContains', viewValue: 'Any Row Contains'},
  {value: 'AllRowsContain', viewValue: 'All Rows Contain'},
  {value: 'FirstRowContains', viewValue: 'First Row Contains'}
];
sqlOperators: SqlOperators[] = [
  // these map to the enums in the java object
  //for the dropdown in the form
  {value: '>', viewValue: 'Is Greater Than (>)'},
  {value: '<', viewValue: 'Is Less Than (<)'},
  {value: '=', viewValue: 'Is Equal to (=)'}
];




constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private controlsService: ControlsService,
    private ControlSpecificDataService: ControlSpecificDataService,
    private SelfServiceDetailsService: SelfServiceDetailsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
            this.controlId = params.get("id");
          });
          this.getValidationStepsOfControl(this.controlId);
      }

      getValidationStepsOfControl(controlId: String): void {
        this.validationSteps= null;
          this.SelfServiceDetailsService.
          getValidationStepsOfControl(controlId)
          .then(result => this.validationSteps = result )
    }


    removeSqlValidation(indexOfStep: number,indexOfValidation): void{
      //index of step is the index in the ValidationSteps array
      //index of validation is the index in sqlValidaionList
      //removes one item starting from the index( so only that item)
      this.validationSteps[indexOfStep].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList.splice(indexOfValidation,1);
      this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();
    }
    addSqlValidationToStep(indexOfStep: number): void{

      var sqlValidation = new SqlValidation();
      this.validationSteps[indexOfStep].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList.push(sqlValidation)
      this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();

      //this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();
    }
    addSqlStepButtonClick(): void{
      let sqlDetail = new SqlDetail();
      let validationStep = new ValidationStep();
      validationStep.type = "Sql"
      validationStep.sqlDetail = sqlDetail;
      this.validationSteps.push(validationStep);
      // make a copy of the array
      // we do this so angular reconises the model has changed
      // and it repopulates the ngfor of ValidationSteps in the html
      this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();
    }
    addDocumentStepButtonClick(): void{
      let documentDetail = new DocumentDetail();
      let validationStep = new ValidationStep();
      validationStep.type = "Document"
      validationStep.documentDetail = documentDetail;
      this.validationSteps.push(validationStep);
      // make a copy of the array
      // we do this so angular reconises the model has changed
      // and it repopulates the ngfor of ValidationSteps in the html
      this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();
    } 
    removeStepFromArray(indexOfStep: number): void{
      //removes one item starting from the index( so only that item)
      this.validationSteps.splice(indexOfStep,1);
      this.validationSteps = this.validationSteps.slice();
    }

    logStep(): void{
      console.log(this.validationSteps);
    }
```

}

My front end component, I loop through the ValidationSteps, and for each SqlDetail, I loop thourgh the SqlValidationList to create the set of inputs for every SqlValidation in the list

```
      <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex">

              <mat-tab label="Control Summary">
                  <p>Summary here</p>
              </mat-tab>
              <mat-tab disabled>
                      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                          <button  (click)="addSqlStepButtonClick()">
                              Add Sql Step
                          </button>
                      </ng-template>
                  </mat-tab>
                  <mat-tab disabled>
                          <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                              <button  (click)="addDocumentStepButtonClick()">
                                  Add Document Step
                              </button>
                          </ng-template>
                      </mat-tab>
                      <mat-tab disabled>
                              <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                                  <button  (click)="logStep()">
                                      Log Step
                                  </button>
                              </ng-template>
                          </mat-tab>
                  <div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">
                          <div *ngIf="step.type == 'Sql' ">
                          <mat-tab label=" Step {{i + 1}}:Sql Step">

                              <form class="example-form">
                                      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="10"><tr>
                                              <td>
                                                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                                <input matInput placeholder="Database Url" name="sqlUrl" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.url"  value="{{step.sqlDetail.url}}">
                                              </mat-form-field>
                                          </td>
                                              <td>
                                                      <mat-form-field>
                                                              <mat-label>Resource Type</mat-label>
                                                              <mat-select #driver [value]="step.sqlDetail.driver" name="sqlDriver" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.driver" >
                                                                      <mat-option *ngFor="let sqlDriver of sqlDrivers"  [value]="sqlDriver.value">
                                                                              {{sqlDriver.viewValue}}
                                                                            </mat-option>
                                                              </mat-select>
                                                            </mat-form-field>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p>Validations</p></td>>
                                            </tr>
                                            <div *ngFor="let sqlValidation of step.sqlDetail.sqlValidationList; let sqlValidationIndex = index ">
                                                <tr>
                                                      <td>
                                                              <mat-form-field>
                                                                      <mat-label>Validation type</mat-label>
                                                                      <mat-select #sqlValidationType [value]="sqlValidation.validationType" name="sqlValidationType" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList[sqlValidationIndex].validationType" >
                                                                              <mat-option *ngFor="let sqlValidationType of sqlValidationTypes"  [value]="sqlValidationType.value">
                                                                                      {{sqlValidationType.viewValue}}
                                                                                    </mat-option>
                                                                      </mat-select>
                                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                      </td>
                                                      <td>
                                                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                                             <input matInput placeholder="Column" name="sqlColumn" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList[sqlValidationIndex].columnName"  value="{{sqlValidation.columnName}}">
                                                             </mat-form-field>
                                                               </td>

                                                          <td>
                                                                  <mat-form-field>
                                                                          <mat-label>Operator</mat-label>
                                                                          <mat-select #sqlOperator [value]="sqlValidation.operator" name="sqlOperator" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList[sqlValidationIndex].operator" >
                                                                                  <mat-option *ngFor="let sqlOperator of sqlOperators"  [value]="sqlOperator.value">
                                                                                          {{sqlOperator.viewValue}}
                                                                                        </mat-option>
                                                                          </mat-select>
                                                                        </mat-form-field>
                                                          </td>
                                                          <td>
                                                   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                                  <input matInput placeholder="Validation value" name="sqlValidation" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.sqlValidationList[sqlValidationIndex].validationValue"  value="{{sqlValidation.validationValue}}">
                                                  </mat-form-field>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                          <button  (click)="removeSqlValidation(i,sqlValidationIndex)">
                                                                  Remove Validation
                                                              </button>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </div>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <td>
                                                          <button  (click)="addSqlValidationToStep(i)"> Add Validation</button>
                                                  </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                              <td>
                                                      <button  (click)="removeStepFromArray(i)"> Remove Step</button>
                                              </td>


                                          </tr></table>
                              </form>
                              </mat-tab>

                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="step.type == 'Document' ">
                          <mat-tab label="Step {{i + 1}}:Document Step">

                              <form class="example-form">
                                      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="10"><tr>
                                              <td>
                                                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                                <input matInput placeholder="Site/path URL" value="{{step.documentDetail.locationUrl}}">
                                              </mat-form-field>
                                          </td>
                                              <td>
                                                      <mat-form-field>
                                                              <mat-label>Resource Type</mat-label>
                                                              <mat-select #documentType [value]="step.documentDetail.locationType" >
                                                                      <mat-option *ngFor="let documentLocationType of documentLocationTypes" [value]="documentLocationType.value">
                                                                              {{documentLocationType.viewValue}}
                                                                            </mat-option>
                                                              </mat-select>
                                                            </mat-form-field>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <p>Validations</p>
                                              </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <button  (click)="removeStepFromArray(i)">
                                                          Remove Step
                                                      </button>
                                          </tr>
                                          </table>
                              </form>
                              </mat-tab>

                  </div>

                  </div>
          </mat-tab-group>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I believe you receive an error in console when you hit the add button. Please double check your console and provide the error

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i just double checked and no error

Comment: you should not use the value for inputs if you use ngmodel.

Comment: After experimenting a bit with constructing the SqlValidation to add to the list, what actually happens is the added SqlValidation is replicated in all sets of forms. So if i change the constructor of a new SqlValidation to have a value of "xxx" in validation, all validation value text boxes get that value

Comment: @tano does the comment above help you figure out what the problem is?

Comment: You should remove the value attribute from the inputs and replace the form tags to divs or remove the name attributes. The angular handles the submission, you dont have to add name to the inputs. The value and ngmodel interferes, except if you use radio where it is needed.

Comment: @tano simply changing the form to a div fixed it, thanks

Comment: @tano this issue has popped up again for me as I had to put the stuff back inside a form as I am using angulars validation functionality on the form. I have removed all the value attirubtes. All the tags have to have names to do validation like here https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/angular-form-ngform-and-two-ways-data-binding

Comment: There's no need for form for angular to validate. If you set the formgroup properly on the div and use simply formgroupname, angular does the job. Have a lookat the reactive form in angular. Much more better approach than the ngmodel. More than one form can cause problems in browsers. Avoid the nested form and try set name attrribute for the form, that can help if you dont prefer reactiveform.